# How can i break up a dimension in np array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array this:

```
arr=[[1]
[2]
[3]]
```

But i would need this:

```
arr2= [1 2 3]
```

How would you make this?

I tried to do this:

```
arr2=np.empty(1)
for i in range(len(arr)):
arr2=np.append(arr2, arr[i][0])
```

But it gives me an extra, smaller number at the beginneng of arr2 and i dont understand why.

Comment: `arr2 = arr.squeeze()`?

Comment: look at `empty(1)` by itself.  And read the `empry` docs. `empty` is not a clone of the list `[]`

Comment: `np.ravel(arr)`

Answer (score 0):

Try slicing:

```py
arr = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
arr[:, 0]
>>> array([1, 2, 3])
```

Syntax `[:, 0]` means *for each subarray, get first element*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you start with a list, and want a list result, just use a list comprehension.  No need for `numpy` baggage.

```
In [21]: alist = [[0],[1],[2]]
In [22]: alist
Out[22]: [[0], [1], [2]]
In [23]: [x[0] for x in alist]
Out[23]: [0, 1, 2]
```

As for that extra number at the beginning, look at what you start with:

```
In [24]: np.empty(1)
Out[24]: array([1.e-08])
```

If you append anything to that, you still have that extra.  `np.empty(1)` is not the same as `[]`  (even though that list is called an empty list).